# Query in getting multiple duplicate rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables `Table1` and `Table2` in which I want to get the total count of duplicate rows:

[image]

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Query tested:

```
SELECT 
    t1.name,
    t1.duplicates,
    ISNULL(t2.active, 0) AS active,
    ISNULL(t3.inactive, 0) AS inactive 
FROM 
    (SELECT
         t1.name, COUNT(*) AS duplicates 
     FROM 
         (SELECT c.name  
          FROM table1 c 
          INNER JOIN table2 as cd on cd.id = c.id)) t1  
    GROUP BY 
        name 
    HAVING 
        COUNT(*) > 1) t1  
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT c.name, COUNT(*) AS active 
     FROM table1 c 
     WHERE name IN (SELECT c.name FROM table1 c) 
     GROUP BY c.name AND status = 'Active' 
     GROUP BY name) t2 ON t1.name = t2.name  
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT c.name, COUNT(*) AS inactive 
     FROM table1 c  
     WHERE name IN (SELECT c.name FROM table1 c GROUP BY c.name)  
       AND status = 'InActive'
     GROUP BY name) t3 ON t1.name = t3.name 
ORDER BY 
    name
```

It is still returning duplicate rows and I'm unable to get the id and creator column

Comment: You need to explain to us how to obtain the second required result from the sample data. What is the rules / logic ?

Comment: You have obfuscated the data so much that it is meaningless and difficult to understand what you are trying to do here. Providing tables and sample data in a consumable format is lightyears betters than images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would pardon `subquery` and `left join`, i'd suggest the following query:

```
select b.*,
       count(creator) as creator_count
 from
  (select a.mainid,
          a.name,
          sum(case when a.status = "active"
              then 1 else 0 end) as active_count,
          sum(case when a.status = "inactive"
              then 1 else 0 end) as inactive_count,
          count(a.name) as duplicate_count
    from table1 as a
    group by a.name
    having count(a.name) > 1) as b
  left join table2 as c
  on b.mainid = c.mainid
  group by c.mainid
  having count(c.creator) > 1
```

rather than forcing our way to join the two table directly. First, derive the information we can get from the `Table1` then join it with the `Table2` to get the `creator count`.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4daa19e/28

Comment: Thanks for the idea it help a lot, however I haven't included the mainid on my query because I'm getting "is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"